# single-lane bridge problem

Tags: c, semaphore

If you're unfamiliar with the problem, it's something like [this](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/Teaching/Resources/MR09/lectures/mk7/img8.htm).

I didn't come to ask for an answer, I have actually finished all of my coding. I have just found that my solution doesn't solve it the best way possible, because my solution only allows one car at a time on the bridge. I was hoping I could get some tips about how to go about using sem_wait and sem_post to solving this problem. I hope to allow traffic flowing the same direction to flow together and not one at a time.

My solution currently looks something like:

(default sem_t north and south = 1 for unlocked for 1 car)

IF northcar then sem_wait(south), sem_wait(north). Cross the bridge, and then sem_post(north), sem_post(south). This is obviously wrong because it's locking the bridge from all cars other than the one on it. I want to enable traffic to flow together. Any ideas?

I am using randomly generated traffic which adds a bit of complexity to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In real life you would solve this problem with a traffic light which is either red-north/green-south, green-north/red-south, or red-north/red-south, and sensors in the approach and exit lanes at both ends of the bridge.

Suppose the light starts out red-north/green-south.  Cars can flow from south to north without stopping.  When a car approaches from the north, it stops at the red light and triggers the north approach sensor.  That makes the light go red-south, but it's still red-north as well.  When all the cars currently on the bridge have left (triggering the north exit sensor on their way out) the light can change to green-north.  That state persists until another car comes from the south and triggers the south approach sensor.

Think about how you'd translate that into code.  (You'll need to use the counting property of semaphores.)

Comment: by counting property you mean incrementing/decrementing with post/wait, as well as sem_getvalue?

Comment: On second thought, one of the conditions is that when no cars are on the bridge the lights on both ends are green. I thought it would work letting the cars race to the lights and the first one there north or south can enter and make the other end red. However I have been unable to do this effectively with sem_wait and sem_post

Comment: Q1: Yes, by counting property I mean incrementing/decrementing with post/wait.  Q2: In real life, you *never ever* make a traffic light be green in conflicting directions simultaneously.  Think about what happens if two cars approach the bridge at high speed from both directions at the same time; the driver who loses the race may not have time to stop.  A similar situation could occur in your code if the semaphores are ever both "green" at the same time.

Comment: This should be solved easily by setting sem_init and using value 1 for north and 0 for south, starting north as green and south red. Then as long as your code never makes both green you should be fine I assume. I wonder why the professor said to set both green with no traffic, hmm.

Answer (score 2):

Single Lane Highway
Problem Description
Certain number of cars are passing a single lane road. Speeds of all cars vary. It is easy to see, that depending on the speeds of the cars various groups will be formed.

Being a single lane road passing/overtaking is not allowed. Given speeds of cars, calculate how many groups can be formed if all possible permutations are taken into account. Refer to example1 for better understanding.

Print number of groups divided by the number of permutations.

Constraints

```
0 <= N < 10 ^ 5

0 <= speed of individual vehicle < 10 ^ 9
```

Input
First line contains an `integer` N, which denotes the number of vehicles

Second line contains N space separated `integers` which denotes the speed of the individual vehicle.

Output
Print number of groups divided by the number of permutations rounded upto 6 decimal places.

Time Limit
1

**Example 1**

Input
3

```
10 20 30
```

**Output**

```
1.833333
```

**Explanation:**

So all possible permutations are:

{10 20 30}
{10 30 20}

```
{20} {10 30}
{20 30} {10}
{30} {10 20}
{30 20} {10}
```

So here there are total 6 permutations, and total number of groups are 11.

So, output is 11/6 = 1.833333

**Example 2**

Input
4

```
56 78 13 92
```

Output

```
2.083333
```

**Explanation:**

So here there are total of 24 permutations,

For example:

```
{56 78 13 92}
{92} {13 78 56}
{56} {13 92 78}
{78 92} {13 56}
.
.
```

So on and so forth. The total number of groups are 50.

So, the output is 50/24 = 2.083333

Answer (score 0):

This is some pseudo python I just whipped up.  Basically block one way and let a limited number cars through.  Depending on how you're using your variables, this might be totally wrong:

```
function main():
    while(true):
        if(north_car):
            let_north_cars_through()
        if(south_car):
            let_south_cars_through()


function let_south_cars_through():
    sem_wait(north)
    for(i = 0; i < max cars; i++):
        if(south_car):
            cross_bridge()
        else:
            break;

    sem_post(north)

function let_north_cars_through()
    sem_wait(south)
    for(i = 0; i < max cars; i++):
        if(north_car):
            cross_bridge()
        else:
            break;

    sem_post(south)
```

Comment: This is pretty interesting, but what if the stream of cars is random, like (n = north and s = south) n,n,n,s,s,n,n,n,n,s,s,s,s. This is kind of how I approached it using a thread as random traffic with a switch case for north/south cars.

Comment: Ah.  I was thinking that north cars would come into one queue and south would come into another queue.  Hmmm..